# How to remove appended HTTP Code in the Error Response Message by ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express JS of nodejs

While sending an internal error message to browser using this code:

```
res.status(500).send('Something happen');
```

I check the response body in the dev tool, and it looks like this:

```
{"message":"500 - \"Something happen\""}
```

This how the code looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res){
   var aPromise = /* implementation here*/     
   aPromise.then(function(user) {
     // Do success implementation
     res.send('OK')
   }, function(err) {
     res.status(500).send('Somethin happen');
   });
});
```

I am using "express": "^4.14.0".
I test it against chrome and firefox, and check their dev tool.

**How to remove the status code 500 from the message?**

Answer (score 0):

What version of Express, and which `dev tool`? When I do

`res.status(500).send('Something happen');`

...and look at the entire HTTP response I only see `Something happen` in the response body (data), while `500` is only part of the response headers.
Maybe it's the dev tool that prints it like that?

Here's the testing code I used, with Express version 4.15.2:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.status(500).send('Something happen');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

...and here is the entire HTTP response I get, as printed by `curl -D - localhost:3000`

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 16
ETag: W/"10-qnwQHvmonx8cVv/OMBPmaKQDE64"
Date: Sun, 19 Mar 2017 12:27:52 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Something happen%
```

...and if I check with a browser - Firefox - it only prints `Something happen`.

Comment: I edit my question above to answer your follow-up question.